# Silex 1.3.4 on PHP 7

Tags: php, silex

I haven't found any official documentation that would confirm Silex 1.3.4 is 100% compatible with PHP 7.

I did find articles that talk about Symfony being 100% compatible with PHP 7 (http://symfony.com/blog/symfony-achieves-100-php7-compatibility).

Apart from having to fully retest my application after the upgrades are done, and without having to switch to Symfony, can anybody provide me with some confidence to go ahead and spend time on the upgrades?

Comment: Just fire up an environment with PHP7 and run the unit tests in Silex.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that could be an easier approach - will consider that. I wonder if anyone already went through that process?

Comment: Thb that's a < 5 min process if you're using vagrant/docker for dev environments - so you're already spending more time here :)